# JavaScript code for moving images randomly around page not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, image

I am using the following code to make several GIF images move around the web page in random directions:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class='img01'> <img src="images/1.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img02'> <img src="images/2.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img03'> <img src="images/3.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img04'> <img src="images/4.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img05'> <img src="images/5.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img06'> <img src="images/6.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img07'> <img src="images/7.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img08'> <img src="images/8.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img09'> <img src="images/9.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img10'> <img src="images/10.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img11'> <img src="images/11.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img12'> <img src="images/12.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img13'> <img src="images/13.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img14'> <img src="images/14.gif"> </div>
 <div class='img15'> <img src="images/15.gif"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#container {height:500px;width:900;}

div.img01 {
position:fixed;
top:100px;
left:100px;
}
```

....

```
div.img13 {
position:fixed;
top:75px;
left:250px;
}

div.img14 {
position:fixed;
top:400px;
left:800px;
}

div.img15 {
position:fixed;
top:340px;
left:200px;
}
```

(I reference every `<div>` tag in the CSS in the same format, with a different set position for each one. I included 13, 14, and 15 because these are the ones I'm having an issue with. I included 1 so you could refer to one that *is* working correctly.)

And lastly, the JavaScript, which is embedded in the main HTML document:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        animateDiv($('.img01'));
        animateDiv($('.img02'));
        animateDiv($('.img03'));    
        animateDiv($('.img04'));  
        animateDiv($('.img05'));
        animateDiv($('.img06'));
        animateDiv($('.img07'));
        animateDiv($('.img08'));
        animateDiv($('.img09'));
        animateDiv($('.img10'));
        animateDiv($('.img11'));
        animateDiv($('.img12'));
        animateDiv($('.img13'));
        animateDiv($('.img14'));
        animateDiv($('.img15'));

});

function makeNewPosition($container) {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $container.height() - 10;
    var w = $container.width() - 10;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv($target) {
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    var oldq = $target.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $target.animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function() {
        animateDiv($target);
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

All of the images are moving around the page just as intended, except 13, 14, and 15. They all remain at the very top and very left of the page, with one image stacked on top of the other. They are not moving at all.

There is nothing different about these three images at all. They are all the same file format and are of a similar size to the other images. I have absolutely no idea why they are not behaving properly.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: this sounds like something related to: not waiting for the images to load and therefore computing with `0px` dimensions.

Comment: Oh, okay thank you. Waiting in what sense though? How would I resolve this issue?